# CSS not applying to child LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a child LWC in another LWC and everything works apart from css in child LWC. I have not provided entire `childLWC.js` since the list in child component gets rendered as expected. Hence, I am only providing `handleHoverChange` method which is relevant to css.

`childLWC.css` does not apply to `li` items i.e. padding added in `reportLabel` css does not get applied. `onmouseover` event, color of text does not get changed as per `backGroundCls`. However, on inspect I can see `handleHoverChange` getting executed. Also, `slds-dropdown` in css file does not get applied to dropdown in `div` section i.e. it is not left aligned, `max-height` is not applied.

If I remove child component reference in parentLWC and include html,css and js code of `childLWC` in parentLWC, css works fine for all scenarios.

`parentLWC` does not have any css file. I have only provided relevant code snippet in `childLWC.js` and not entire js code.

`parentLWC.html`:

```
<template>
<lightning-card>
  <c-child-lwc para1={reports}></c-child-lwc>
</lightning-card>
</template>
```

`childLWC.html`:

```
<template>
<div id="listbox-id-01" class="slds-dropdown" role="listbox">
    <ul class="slds-listbox slds-listbox_vertical" role="presentation">
        <template for:each={para1} for:item="report">
            <li role="presentation" class="slds-listbox__item" key={report.value} >
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="color:black;">
                  <p key={report.value} onmouseover={handleHoverChange} class="reportLabel">{report.label}</p>
                </a>
            </li>           
        </template>
    </ul> 
</div>
```

`childLWC.js`

```
handleHoverChange(event){
    const evt = event.currentTarget;
    evt.classList.toggle('backGroundCls');
}
```

`childLWC.css`

```
.slds-dropdown {
left: 30%;
width: 250px;
overflow-y: auto;
max-height: 250px;
}

.backGroundCls {
color: rgb(0,109,204);
}

.reportLabel {
padding-bottom: 5px;
padding-left: 2px;
}
```

Comment: You can't just say "doesn't work" and expect a reasonable answer. How does it not work? What's wrong? Please [edit] your question to include the desired and unexpected behaviors.

Comment: Updated my question.

Comment: Not an answer, but btw the code is inconsistent with the templates. For example, the childLWC template relies on a property in the childLWC "controller", called "para1", which doesn't exist in your code.

Comment: @PhilW, I have not provided entire js code of child component, the reason being list gets rendered properly, just that css is not getting applied. I have provided code which are relevant to css changes.

Comment: its a typo right in parentLWC.html where you have not ended </template> and </lightning-card>

Comment: Yeah,corrected. It was a typo in this question. Actual component does not have typos.

Comment: strange its working fine for me also see in pg is this how you wanted https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/ZcpuLi6U/4/edit

Comment: Yeah, this is basically the same code but it works in playground

Comment: i also deployed this to org and it works fine there too.

Comment: I could not figure out what was wrong in childLWC component. I deleted it and created child component with same code again and this time it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not figure out what was wrong in childLWC component. I deleted it and created child component with same code again and this time it works

Comment: Probably CSS file wasn't deployed correctly to the server or something

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue was misspelling the name of the .css file